# Wrong parsing of ` =>` in comments

Tags: bug, comments, markdown-rendering

I wrote this comment:

```
@Kusalananda I was thinking that `sqlite3.no value` would be taken away 
with matching the first ` =>` in ` => /some/path/php/extensions/no-debug-
non-zts-20160303 sqlite3.no value => no value`. So this would have been 
matched ` => /some/path/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303 
sqlite3.no value`. Why was only ` => /some/path/php/extensions/no-debug-
non-zts-20160303` matched?
```

However, it produced this output:

[image]

Removing space from  `=>` to `=>` helped but the space should have been there

Note in a post this would be formatted as:

> @Kusalananda I was thinking that `sqlite3.no value` would be taken away with matching the first `=>` in `=> /some/path/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303 sqlite3.no value => no value`. So this would have been matched `=> /some/path/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303 sqlite3.no value`. Why was only `=> /some/path/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303` matched?

Comment: think this happens in markdown syntax _ in general_. So not sure if it is _a bug_

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306009/349538

Comment: But it doesn't happen in post's body

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105316/my-comment-code-block-was-not-converted-properly-is-this-a-bug => status-by-design

Comment: @SurajRao Status-by-_poor_-design.

Comment: even if it works as implemented, works as designed, and works as specified, I still consider this to be a bug. saying it's not a bug is like saying spectre is not a cpu bug because the spectre-cpus work as designed. designs and requirements can have bugs too.

Comment: @Michael not really an appropriate comparison, as spectre is a vulnerability while this is simply an inconvenience to those that want it to work differently.

Comment: As discussed above, this has nothing to do with parsing `=>`.